# assigning a value to specific words in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nlp

Hi I have a dataframe consisting of 7989 rows × 1 columns.
The different rows are consequences from different maritime piracy attack.

I then want to assign a value to the different rows depending on whether or not a specific word is included in one of the different list below. The value assigned will then depend on the different list.

The 6 lists:

```
five =['kill','execute','dead']
four =['kidnap','hostag','taken','abduct']
three =['injur','wound','assault']
two =['captur','hijack']
one =['stolen','damage','threaten','robber','destroy']
zero =['alarm','no','none']
```

I Have tried to do it like this:

```
df['five']=df.apply(lambda x: '5' if x == 'five' else '-')
```

and `df` is my dataframe

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you embed a short example in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can create dictionary for each list with value for number, [merge all dictionaries together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/2901002) and then set new columns by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'outcom':[['kill','dead'],['abduct','aaaa'],['hostag']]})

#same way add another lists
five = ['kill','execute','dead']
four = ['kidnap','hostag','taken','abduct']   
three =['injur','wound','assault']
two =['captur','hijack']
one =['stolen','damage','threaten','robber','destroy']
zero =['alarm','no','none']    

#same way add another dicts
d5 = dict.fromkeys(five, '5')
d4 = dict.fromkeys(four, '4')
d3 = dict.fromkeys(three, '3')
d2 = dict.fromkeys(two, '2')
d1 = dict.fromkeys(one, '1')
d0 = dict.fromkeys(zero, '0')

d = {**d5, **d4, **d3, **d2, **d1, **d0}
print (d)

for k, v in d.items():
    df[k] = np.where(df['outcom'].apply(lambda x: k in x), v, '-')

print (df)
           outcom kill execute dead kidnap hostag taken abduct
0    [kill, dead]    5       -    5      -      -     -      -
1  [abduct, aaaa]    -       -    -      -      -     -      4
2        [hostag]    -       -    -      -      4     -      -
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited

you can use the `loc` function ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)) like so:

import pandas as pd

```
five = ["I", "like"]
df = pd.DataFrame(["I", "like", "bacon", "in", "the", "morning"], columns=["Words"])
     Words
0        I
1    likes
2    bacon
3       in
4      the
5  morning

df["New"] = df["Words"].copy()
df.loc[df["New"] == "I", "New"] = 5

     Words      New
0        I        5
1     like     like
2    bacon    bacon
3       in       in
4      the      the
5  morning  morning
```

you can then use a for-loop to help you

Comment: Thank you so much! 
But I would to make a new column where I have a value 0-5 depending on if the word is included. And it is not possible to say 



df['new_name_column'] = df.where(df ==['kidnap','hostag','taken','abduct], 4)

Comment: I guess I could also make a loop, but it doesn't work. :/

Comment: That is probably because i made a mistake, unlike numpy pandas' `where` replaces the values that DONT hold the condition

Comment: @SofieAmalieBodenhoff I fixed my answer and ran the code, it works :)

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work.  I have a a column with multiple words is that the problem?

Comment: @SofieAmalieBodenhoff - I think you are right, answer is wrong, because cannot working with lists.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help I think I found a way to make it work:

```
 list_of_words = zero + one + two + three + four + five

     outcome_refined = df_Stop2['outcome'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item 
      in list_of_words])



 outcome_numbered=[] #Create an empty list

def max_val(list): #Ensures that then we only get the largest possible value

maximum_value = 0

for i in list:
   
   if i > maximum_value:

        maximum_value = i

return [maximum_value]

        
 #Make sure that you loop through each of the lists
    
 for words in outcome_refined:
    tmp = [] #Create a temprorary empty list
    for word in words:
      if word in zero:
          word = 0
      elif word in one:
          word = 1
      elif word in two:
          word = 2
      elif word in three:
          word = 3
      elif word in four:
          word = 4
      elif word in five:
          word = 5   
      tmp.append(word)
    tmp = max_val(tmp)
    outcome_numbered.append(tmp)


df_Stop['outcome_numbered']=outcome_numbered.copy()   

df_Stop
```

[Finally working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9eQ8.png)